# Fastly cache invalidation fastly-rails and friendly ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, friendly-id, fastly

I'm struggling with cache invalidation on Fastly and a rails app I work on. I'm using the fastly-rails gem and have confirmed the CNAMEs are set up correct. The issue is essentially as such:

A page is cached and served correctly from Fastly when there is no record of it in the cache. The resources surrogate keys are set using [fastly-rails](https://github.com/fastly/fastly-rails) in a before action...

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cache_control_headers, only: [:index, :show]

...

def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  ...
  set_surrogate_key_header @school.record_key
end
```

from there, the page is cached and the next visit is served from Fastly servers. Now, in my active-admin controller action I have a call to invalidate the record in the cache after any updates are made as such:

```
ActiveAdmin.register School do
  
  ...

  def update
    super
    @school.purge
  end

end
```

this does ultimately end up invalidating the record on Fastly's end however, when I visit the URL /schools/:resource_slug I am still served the stale content from Fastly but if I visit /schools/:id I am served correctly from the application and then a second visit is served from the Fastly servers.

Any thoughts? Any one have a similar issue?

Comment: Can you share the code that makes use of the friendly_id? From the looks of it, this is only supporting finding by the id.

Comment: Friendly ID supports finding a model which extends FreindlyId to find by id and will find the resource by slug name by default.

Comment: I'd suggest verifying that the `@school.record_key` value for both GET /schools/:id and /schools/:resource_slug is the same.

Comment: I've resolved this and it ultimately had nothing to do with slugging nor friendly ID. Thank you for the suggestions.